# Плавная смена спрайта у изображения

Tags: c#, unity3d

Я работаю над игрой в жанре визуальной-новеллы, в юнити 2д. Необходима плавная смена фона. Я пришел к выводу, что проще всего, плавно сменить спрайт изображения. Пробовал играться с rgba, но не вышло. Помогите, если можете, приложите примеры кода, пожалуйста

Comment: А ты пытаешся сделать это одной картинкой чтоли?

Comment: Да, одно изображение, которое меняет Спрайт

Comment: А ты попробуй два. Одно появляется поверх другова.

Comment: Как мне сделать другой прозрачным? Просто мне необходим плавный переход

Comment: Есть движки напрямую заточенные под визуальные новеллы. Юнити под это не заточен и, если чесно, то это довольно глупая идея его использовать. Код писать сложнее, а конечная игра будет весить значительно больше. Как и жрать ресурсов. Думаю, стоит лучше подумать над выбором движка. Что до того как сделать.... Все же лучше 2 изображения сделать и не запариваться.

Comment: Да, осознание этого пришло достаточно поздно, но я уже многое написал на юнити, и увы, пути назад нет.

Comment: 1. Путь назад всегда есть. 2. Тем более, что писать скрипты под правильно заточенный движок под визуальные новеллы будет значительно проще и занимать в 10 раз меньше времени. А то и вовсе не нужно будет если это какой-то юайно-продвинутый двиг. 3. Мало кто порадуется визуальной новелле, которая будет безумно жрать батарею. А Юнити ее жрет как не в себя, просто потому, что Юнити всегда грузит полноценный 3д движок и 3д сцену.